# How do I prevent Metro from randomly reloading my app?

Tags: react-native, android-virtual-device, metro-bundler

My React Native app has a login screen which presents a modal with username/password inputs and a "log in" button. I'm running it on the Android emulator with various AVDs, API v28+, RN v0.61.5, MacOS 10.15.

Approximately 95% of the time, in the course of entering text into these two fields, Metro reloads the app in the background for some reason. The modal remains visible after the refresh, but the fields and button are no longer interactable, and I have to reinstall the app in order to do anything (upon which the whole cycle repeats, until occasionally I get lucky and am able to log in).

I've tried turning off fast refresh in the dev menu, cleaning the Android build, clearing the yarn cache, reinstalling the node modules, deleting all watchers, wiping the AVD, and restarting the machine.

Comment: Hmm quite odd, i've seen the metro bundler do some weird things but never that, while it does sound like a bad configuration I'm curious how these text inputs are setup. There's also usually a metro config file in the root directory, might be worth glancing through there and the other config files there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this wound up being an emulator issue. The text I was entering in one of my inputs contained a double R, which was interpreted as the reload command, rather than as input.

So now I just type slower....